# Is it possible to get the foreground window from a system tray app in windows using python pywin32?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am using the pywin32's demo win32gui_taskbar.py & extending it to take a screen shot of the window if a particular window is currently the active/foreground window. 
The `screen_shot` function is called whenever the user left click's on the system tray icon

```
import win32api, win32service
import win32gui, win32ui
import win32con, winerror
import sys, os
import time
from PIL import Image

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        msg_TaskbarRestart = win32gui.RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarCreated");
        message_map = {
                msg_TaskbarRestart: self.OnRestart,
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
                win32con.WM_COMMAND: self.OnCommand,
                win32con.WM_USER+20 : self.OnTaskbarNotify,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbarDemo"
        wc.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW;
        wc.hCursor = win32api.LoadCursor( 0, win32con.IDC_ARROW )
        wc.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.

        # Don't blow up if class already registered to make testing easier
        try:
            classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        except win32gui.error, err_info:
            if err_info.winerror!=winerror.ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS:
                raise

        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow( wc.lpszClassName, "Taskbar Demo", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        self._DoCreateIcons()
    def _DoCreateIcons(self):
        # Try and find a custom icon
        hinst =  win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( os.path.split(sys.executable)[0], "pyc.ico" ))
        if not os.path.isfile(iconPathName):
            # Look in DLLs dir, a-la py 2.5
            iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( os.path.split(sys.executable)[0], "DLLs", 

"pyc.ico" ))
        if not os.path.isfile(iconPathName):
            # Look in the source tree.
            iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( os.path.split(sys.executable)[0], "..\\PC\

\pyc.ico" ))
        if os.path.isfile(iconPathName):
            icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        else:
            print "Can't find a Python icon file - using default"
            hicon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)

        flags = win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "Python Demo")
        try:
            win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)
        except win32gui.error:
            # This is common when windows is starting, and this code is hit
            # before the taskbar has been created.
            print "Failed to add the taskbar icon - is explorer running?"
            # but keep running anyway - when explorer starts, we get the
            # TaskbarCreated message.

    def OnRestart(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    print "In onrestart"
        self._DoCreateIcons()

    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_DELETE, nid)
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

    def OnTaskbarNotify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
            print "You clicked me."            
            print win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
            print ".." + win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) 
            self.screen_shoot()
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            print "You double-clicked me - goodbye"
            win32gui.DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
            print "You right clicked me."            
        return 1

    def screen_shot(self):
        wndh = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()   
    if "Notepad" in win32gui.GetWindowText(wndh):
            print "Inside if"
            hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(wndh)
            mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
            saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
            saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
            left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(wndh)
            w = right - left
            h = bot - top
            saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
            saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)
            saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h),  mfcDC,  (0, 0),  win32con.SRCCOPY)
        bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
            bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
            im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'],
                                          bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
                                          bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
            saveDC.DeleteDC()
            mfcDC.DeleteDC()
            win32gui.ReleaseDC(wndh, hwndDC)
            im.save("c:\screenshot" + str(int(time.time())) + ".png")


    def OnCommand(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        id = win32api.LOWORD(wparam)
        if id == 1023:
            import win32gui_dialog
            win32gui_dialog.DemoModal()
        elif id == 1024:
            print "Hello"
        elif id == 1025:
            print "Goodbye"
            win32gui.DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        else:
            print "Unknown command -", id

def main():
    w=MainWindow()
    win32gui.PumpMessages()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

In the above code the control never goes inside the if condition in the screen_shot function.
How can get this program working? The same screen shot logic works fine when its run as a normal application.

Comment: So have you tried printing the result of `win32gui.GetWindowText(wndh)`? What was it?

Comment: I have tried to print it gives me a value (handle) but does not match to that of notepad application. The getwindowtext returns a empty string

Comment: Right, so that's the core of the problem. you may get more help if you try to pare the problem down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question...
Just realised task bar is also another "window" & upon clicking the system tray icon the focus is shifted to the task window. Which is what is reported as the foreground window & get window text for this window is blank string. I verified this by slightly modifying my program.
In the MainWindow class init function after the `win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)` icon init call added the following code to verify it

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    wndh = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()   
    print "windowndh" + str(wndh)
    if "Notepad" in win32gui.GetWindowText(wndh):
        # Take screen shot
        print "Inside if"
```