# How to open a program from the system tray in windows 11 with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, psutil

I want to open my keyboard software that's hidden in the system tray on startup for it to load the current keyboard layout, and then close the program.

The current problem is if the program is not open on the desktop and if it's only in the system tray (taskbar hidden icons tray) the .FindWindow returns 0

So i need to open the program from the system tray so it can load everything

```
from time import sleep
import psutil
import win32gui
import win32con


def end_task(task_name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == task_name:
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "CMSEngine")
            print(hwnd)
            win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
            sleep(10)
            proc.kill()


# sleep(240)
end_task("CMS.exe")
```

Comment: Does this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37439586/1502898

Comment: thanks for the response, but no it does not, also that code is Python 2 many things have changed since then so I'm pretty sure most of that is outdated. But thanks for the response.

Comment: What about something like `win32gui.FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "CMSEngine")`? This seems to be how pywin32 checks for the system tray: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/70ddf693927fa1635f15e9ef41eb1aea37fdf32a/win32/Demos/desktopmanager.py

Comment: Still didn't work, it just returns 0